# How can I fetch another remote repository?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have two remote repository in my project.

> `git remote 
>   origin 
>   origin-bitbucket`

When I run `git fetch` command, fetching my origin (github) repository. But I want to fetch origin-bitbucket repository. Which command should I use to?

`git remote -v` output:

```
origin-bitbucket    xxx.git (fetch)
origin-bitbucket    xxx.git (push) 
origin  xxx.git (fetch) 
origin  xxx.git (push)
```

Comment: `man git-fetch`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk what is this? edit: ok. info about git fetch

Comment: He probably means that `git help fetch`, or, on Linux for instance, `man git-fetch` would give you the answer.

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v` ?

Comment: The solution below should work. What is the error returned when running that command?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness When I running `git merge origin-bitbucket`, returning this error: `merge: origin-bitbucket - not something we can merge`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git fetch origin-bitbucket` should work.

[Source](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)

Comment: but when I try to push repository using `git push -u origin-bitbucket master` is giving  `failed to push some refs to xxx.git'`

Comment: @dgknca is your question about fetching or about pushing?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness both. Because I give still `hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.` error.

Comment: Seems like you didn't merge after fetching, so your local isn't up-to-date with the remote.

Comment: @hur When I running `git merge origin-bitbucket`, returns this error: `merge: origin-bitbucket - not something we can merge`

Comment: `git merge origin-bitbucket/[branch]` is the syntax.

Comment: @hur `merge: origin-bitbucket/[master] - not something we can merge`

Comment: [branch] without the brackets